# How to use a rowfilter on a dataview for the character asterisk?

Tags: asp.net, dataview, rowfilter

I have been attempting to use a row filter on a dataview.

It works great for almost all characters except for when I pass it an asterisk.

```
Dim filterString As String = ""
filterString = "MY_COMPARISON_FIELD LIKE '%" + PassedChar.ToUpper + "%'"
MyDataView.RowFilter = filterString
```

So, when I pass an asterisk above in as the passedchar var, it just filters by all.

Brings me back to the whole dos `*.*` usage, which is what I am sure it is doing, wildcarding the asterisk.  Anyone, ever figured out how to search on just the asterisk as a char not a wildcard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enclose in brackets

Refer this http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the * in your filter condition by using square brackets [ ].

Have a look at this link:

[MSDN: Data Column Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)